# How to add environment variable value to YAML file?

Tags: yaml, environment-variables

I'm having `.env` file. which contains:

```
User_Name= username
Pass_Word= password
```

How to add the above variable values `username` and `password` only to the yaml.

I mentioned in this way:

```
Website:
   USER:
     Login: ${User_Name}
     Pass: ${Pass_Word}
```

Expected Result while parsed in python file:

```
Login = username
Pass = password
```

But I'm getting strings like below while I actually need to get `username` and `password`:

```
Login = '${User_Name}'
Pass = '${Pass_Word}'
```

Comment: You should explicitly put all variables in the corresponding .yaml file, e.g. in the begining. After that you can reference them in the file.

Comment: @Andrey can please show me how to do it. I'm new to this thing. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you need configuration like this:

```
username: "username"
password: "password"

website:
  user:
    login: ${username}
    pass: ${password}
```

Comment: I'm doing the same thing but while I'm reading **login** value in python I'm getting the value as  **'${username}'** instead of **username**